# Calling batch file with parameter containing space

Tags: batch-file, whitespace, command-line-arguments, space

I have a very simple problem:

```
call myBatch.bat "K:\dir name with spaces\eatThis.xml"
```

Which will not work, it will stop with

```
K:\dir does not exist
```

Could you please point me to the SO question addressing such an issue? I've already dug myself through quite a lot of SO questions regarding batch files and whitespaces in parameters but I guess the solution to my problem must have been ignored accidentally.

--

OK, after some debugging it turned out that it was not the batch file that was faulty but the Java application that invokes `String.split(" ");` to separate multiple arguments from each other. So when one argument contains a space, in its path, the application logic falls apart. As the original question no more describes what the real problem is, shall I rewrite it completely or write a new one? Anyway, my bad, feel free to downvote is.

Comment: Obviously the bug is in `myBatch.bat`, without seeing it, it's a bit tricky to find the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created the following `mybatch.bat` and started it with `call myBatch.bat "K:\dir name with spaces\eatThis.xml"` Output is:

```
"K:\dir name with spaces\eatThis.xml"
```

Mybatch.bat:

```
echo off&setlocal
echo "%~1"
```

Comment: I added `echo off&setlocal` and replaced `%*` with `"%~1"` as well. However I still get `K:\dir does not exist`. I must be missing something.

Comment: Put double quotes around `"%~1"`

Comment: You mean `"%~1"` or `""%~1""`? Anyway, I tried both, I tried even without quotes, but neither of them worked.

Comment: So please add more code from your `mybatch.bat` to your question. I mean `"%~1"`. Don't know, what you are doing with the parameter.

Comment: The parameter gets passed to a Java application the following way:

`java -cp %_classpath% com.mypackage.MyClass "%~1"`

(`%_classpath%` variable is set to contain the necessary .jar files)

Comment: Actually, classpath is set the following way: `SET "_classpath=myJar1.jar;myJar2.jar;myJar3.jar"`. The following line says `java -cp %_classpath% com.mypackage.MyClass "%~1"`.

Comment: And if you put an `echo "%~1"` on the beginning of mybatch.bat, what says the output? (you can place `pause` after it to see

Comment: Endoro, I'm very thankful for your patience. Please take a look at the updated problem description. I apparently messed it up pretty much.

Comment: OK, so it belongs on your java program :)

Comment: Yes. The content of `args[]` is joined with spaces, then it gets split among them. It works fine as long as no argument contains any additional spaces. But since each arg begins with a drive letter, I replaced `String.split(" ")` with `String.split(" .:\\\\")` and now it seems to work fine. Anyway, I'm utterly grateful for your patience and sorry about being such an idiot.